# which is better for building website about game forecasts : coding or using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make game forecast website  ( like "betegy.com", "sport-bet24.ru" "www.chempionbet.ru" )  but I don't know which one is better for my website.First of all there must be registration and card balance buttons.For making this website which one I should prefer ?

Comment: do you ask for library, framework, blog system? which?

Comment: Voting to close, this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: sagol Kamuran,spor bahisleri ucun website acmaq istedim.Hansinin daha faydali olacagini sorusurdum.Siteni wordpressle mi yoxsa ozum kodlasdiraraq hazirlasam yaxsi olar. Amma artiq qerar verdim wordpressden istifade edecem.
(thanks everyone)